# Elements in extension field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose $\alpha\in\text{GF}(q^n)\setminus\text{GF}(q)$. Then there exists an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in\text{GF}(q)[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. My question is that whether this $f(x)$ is unique for each $\alpha$ ? Is there any well-known result on this ?

Comment: This much is true for *any* algebraic fields extension $\,K/L\,$: for any $\,k\in K-L\,$ there exists an irreducible polynomial over $\,L\,$ for which $\,k\,$ is a root. If we impose the condition to be monic on that polynomial then this is unique, and anyway the minimal irreduclbe pol. of an algebraic element is unique up to multiplication by units (i.e., constant polynomials),

Comment: @DonAntonio,you are right. I can see the same idea is applicable in general. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to multiplication by a nonzero element of $GF(q)$, it's unique.  Fix some  $0\ne f(x)\in GF(q)[x]$ with minimal degree such that $f(\alpha)=0$.  Since $f(x)$ has minimal degree, it must be irreducible.  Then, given any other polynomial $g(x)\in GF(q)[x]$ with $g(\alpha)=0$, you can divide $g(x)$ by $f(x)$ to
get polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ in $GF(q)[x]$ with
$$
g(x)=q(x)f(x)+r(x), \ \ \ \ \deg r(x) < \deg f(x).
$$
Then, since $g(\alpha)=f(\alpha)=0$, $r(\alpha)=0$, so by minimality of $\deg f(x)$, $r(x)$ must be the zero polynomial.  This proves that $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$, so, if $g(x)$ is also irreducible, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be nonzero constant multiples of each other.

This is a standard result that works for any $\alpha$ algebraic over any field $K$ just as well as for $\alpha$ algebraic over $GF(q)$.

Comment: I think you idea works, albeit the proof should be reorganised a bit. Your argument shows that $h(x)=f(x)$ or $g(x)$ and hence $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ divide each other, and so they are equal.